# Find all integers $n>1$ such that$\frac{2^n+1}{n+1}$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $n>1$ such that  $\frac{2^n+1}{n+1}$ is an integer.

---

Second attempt : I'd like to know if it's correct or not. Thank you.

Since $\frac{2^n+1}{n+1}$ for all integers $n>1$ is equivalent to  $\frac{2^{n-1} \;+1}{n}$ for all integers $n>2$,

we will find all integers $n>2$ such that $\frac{2^{n-1}+1}{n}$ is an integer instead.

Let $n=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^l p_i^{k_i}$, where $k_i \geq 1$, $p_i \in \text{prime}$.

Let $p_j$ be prime such that $p_j\mid n$ and $p_j$ has minimum $v_2(p_j-1)$.

Since $n \mid 2^{n-1}+1$, so $n\in$ odd, then $p_j\in$ odd.

so $v_2(p_j-1) \geq 1$, i.e.,  there exist $r_j, m_j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m_j \in \text{odd}$ such that $p_j-1=2^{r_j}\cdot m_j$

we have $p_j \equiv 1 (\bmod{2^{r_j}})$

Since $v_2(p_j-1)$ is minimum and $n\in$ odd, so $n \equiv 1 (\bmod{2^{r_j}})$

then we can write $n$ in the form, $n = 2^mt+1$, where $m, t \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m\geq r_j$

so $n \equiv -1 (\bmod{2^m})$

$-1 \equiv 2^{n-1} \equiv 2^{ 2^m \cdot t}\equiv 2^{ 2^m\cdot t\cdot m_j} (\bmod{p_j})$, since $m_j$ is odd,

$-1 \equiv 2^{(2^{r_j} \cdot m_j) 2^{m-r_j}\;\cdot t} (\bmod{p_j})$

$-1 \equiv 2^{(p_j-1)  2^{m-r_j}\;\cdot t} (\bmod{p_j})$

$-1 \equiv 1 (\bmod{p_j})$, then $p_j=2$, contradicts that $p_j\in$ odd.

Therefore, there is no such $n$.

Comment: +1 for showing your work. You had $2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, and $2^{m-1}\equiv-1\pmod p$. How do those two imply that $2^2\equiv1\pmod p$? The order of two modulo $p$ is a factor of both $p-1$ and $2(m-1)$, but those two might have a common factor larger than $2$. For example when $m=p=5$. You lost me at that point.

Comment: Admittedly my comment above totally misses the obvious point that the order of two must not be a factor of $m-1$. I'm just not connecting the dots now :-).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen♦ I've added the detail, please kindly check.

Comment: My point really was that $\gcd(2m-2,p-1)$ is not necessarily a factor of two.

Comment: $m-1$ and $p-1$ can share an odd factor, even with the condition $p\mid m$. For example, $m=66, p=11$. In this case, $\gcd(2m-2,p-1)$ will be larger than 2.

Comment: Could someone please check if there is any error in my second attempt ?

Comment: @orlp, $\frac{2^3+1}{3+1}$ for $n=3$ is equivalent to  $\frac{2^{4-1}+1}{4}$ for $n=4$.

Comment: Oh like that... I'm an idiot.

Comment: @orlp. sorry for not expressing the idea clearly.

Comment: I've already corrected some mistakes in my second attempt. Please check.

Comment: Can you tell me what does mean $v_2(p_j-1)$? Is it a p-adic valuation? Be clear,  answering me, please. Thank you.

Comment: @Piquito, $v_p(x)$ is the greatest power in which a prime $p$ divides $x$.
, if $v_p(x) = \alpha$ then $p^{\alpha} \mid x$ but $p^{\alpha+1} \not\mid x$.

Comment: @Piquito, for example $v_2(12) = 2$ because $2^2 \mid 12$ but $ 2^3 \not\mid 12$.

Comment: I think your mistake is to have put $n = 2^mt+1$ because of $p_j-1=2^{r_j}\cdot m_j$ you can get $$n=(2^{r_j}m_j+1)^{k_j}\prod_{i\ne j}p_i^{k_i}=2^mt+\prod_{i\ne j}p_i^{k_i}\ne2^mt+1$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your example with $v_2(12)$. It was not necessary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  The following procedure is a sort of descent proving the impossibility of solution.

It is obvious that the denominator cannot be even so $n$ should be even and the quotient (supposing it is integer) should be odd.
$$2^{2n}+1=(2n+1)(2k+1)\iff2^{2n}=4kn+2(k+n)\iff2^{2n-1}=2kn+k+n$$ It follows that $k$ and $n$ have the same parity. We have to consider the two possible cases which give 
$$►(1)\text{ both odd: } 2^{2n-1}==2^3k_1n_1+(2+1)(k_1+n_1)+2^2$$
$$►(2)\text{ both even: } 2^{2n-1}=2^3k_1n_1+2(k_1+n_1) $$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ give respectively $$2^{n-2}=2^2k_1n_1+(2+1)(k_1+n_1)+2\\2^{n-2}=2^2k_1n_1+k_1+n_1$$ 
Both cases require $k_1$ and $n_1$ have the same parity.

Iterating the procedure we get in each step $k_i$ and $n_i$ have the same parity 
which leads, after sufficient iterations, to an equality in which an integer is equal to another greater integer. Contradiction.

$$\text{ A concise example}$$ $$(2^6+1)=(6+1)(2k+1)=14k+6+1\iff2^6=14k+6\iff2^5=7k+3\\ 2^5=7k+3\Rightarrow2^5=7(2k_1+1)+3=14k_1+10\iff2^4=7k_1+5\\2^4=7k_1+5\Rightarrow2^4=7(2k_2+1)+5=14k_2+12\iff2^3=7k_2+6\text{
 absurde }.$$

Comment: Thank you, Piquito, "$2^{2n}+1=(2n+1)(2k+1)$", why is $2n+1$ a factor of $2^{2n}+1$ ? $(6+1)$ is not a factor of $2^6+1$.

Comment: @carat: You are welcome. In order $\dfrac{2^n+1}{n+1}$ be an integer, $n+1$ should be odd because $2^n+1$ is obviously odd so can not be divisible by any even. This requires that n be even. Therefore we should assume that $n$ is $2n$ so the question is about the quotient $\dfrac{2^{2n}+1}{2n+1}$. On the other hand it is clear that $6+1$ is not a factor of $2^{2n}+1$ and the concise example is used to illustrate the procedure arriving to an absurde.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Did you see the mistake in my work ?

Comment: @carat: I have the (bad) habit of not reading other answers before finding mine. My deficiency in English has made me put HINT but I should not have done it because in fact I have completely solved your problem. I'll look at your answer and discuss in another comment.

Comment: There is one point I'm not so clear is the iteration, is your method called Infinite descend ?

Comment: @carat:Created by Fermat, the method of infinite descent has had a remarkable development and is currently used with sophisticated and difficult "mise à jour" from the original method, especially in high geometry-algebraic arithmetic. This is why I said "a sort of descent" without daring to say “descent” bluntly.